# Task Scheduler to run a batch file to call a powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, task, scheduler

I have created a Powershell script that I call from a batch file, and everything works fine when I call the batch file.  The problem I am running into is I need to set the batch file to run in Task Scheduler.  It starts fine, but it keeps hanging up because the task scheduler never says "The operation completed successfully" (0x0).  Instead, it stays at "The task is currently running" (0x41301).  Please advise, and I understand this is not the most ideal way to call a Powershell Script but for our environment and limited knowledge of scripting it works the best for us.

Comment: You can run the PowerShell script directly from the Task Scheduler. Can you give more info what the script is doing and why you need batch /cmd file to run it and some code example.

Comment: you might wanna have a look at posh scheduled jobs

Comment: @JaquelineVanek You need a new spellchecker. There's that "posh" word again :)

Comment: @DavidPostill aint it funny peeps keep addin teh posh tag while they dont seem to be interested in posh in teh slightest? sorry, kinda mad I am atm :D -- just wanted to ask a question on PoSh classes, hardly even a hobbyist myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should just use Task Scheduler to run PowerShell.

Create a new task, go to `Actions` tab, then choose `New...`, and inside this new window, you can run any program, like you run something from cmd.

Inside `Program/script` square, you simply put `Powershell.exe`, and inside `Add arguments (optional)` powershell arguments. This will work the same, as you would type in normal command line:

```
powershell <arguments>
```

So if you want to run script, that is saved in your disk, simply put this in arguments list:

```
C:\LocalisationOfScript\script.ps1 "argument 1" argument2
```

If you want more options, just add common parameters before this:

```
-windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass C:\LocalisationOfScript\script.ps1 "argument 1" argument2
```

Of even this:

```
-windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass if (Test-path C:\script\script.ps1) { C:\script\script.ps1 "argument 1" argument2 } else { return -1 }
```

And finally:

```
Start-Process Powershell.exe -argumentslist "-a -b -c copy" -windowstyle hidden -wait -erroraction stop
```

You can even add try, catch to last example.

Comment: A better approach might be:
inside the .bat file add the `powershell` perfix and then just run the original file from the task scheduler

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the comments, i researched you advice and came across the exit command i forgot to add to the end of my script, so when i call my script it left the session to exchange open after i applied the exit command to the end of the script the program has been running without error (knock on wood) sense the fix and after i closed and reopened Task Scheduler the last run message changed to (0x0)